SwiftUI Image with contentMode .fill overlapping views
Consider this simple CardView in SwiftUI:
struct CardView: View {
    let cardNumber: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("bg1")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(height: 100)
                .clipped()

            Spacer()

            Text("Card: \(cardNumber.description)")
                .font(.title.bold())

            Button("Test") { print("Tapped") }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .background(.green)
        .frame(height: 260)
        .border(.blue)
    }
}


The VStack is set to height 260 and the Image is set to height 100 and with the content model .fill. I understand that we need to set .clipped() to prevent the image from extend beyond the view's bounds.
If I render this view alone, everything works fine i.e. tap the button and print "Tapped".
However, if I'd render multiple CardView, for example put this CardView inside a VStack or ScrollView. The clipped image will start overlapping and the Test button will no-longer work.
From the UI debugger I can see it render as below inside the VStack.

Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

I realized that .clipped family will not prevent the Image itself from tap action, you need to add .contentShape, which makes the Image not overwhelm the surrounding context:
Image("bg1")
    ...
    .contentShape(Rectangle()) //<- here


Thanks @sonle, that works! may I follow up a bit: how come it works without the .contentShape when render only one CardView?

IMO, I think it's because of layout priority, you had two views in a VStack, and the second one will overlap the first one. However, I did try with a single view before with a larger image, and it still happened until .contentShape was added, in the case you have actions, i.e a tap gesture over the entire CardView, tapping outside the view (visually) will also trigger the gesture.
